# Privileged instruction exception thrown when modifying referred int

Tags: c++, exception

I've been doing some experiments in C++ with const-ness and member functions, and I've written the following code:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    int& refToInt;
    MyClass(int x) : refToInt(x) { ; }
    void changeValue() const { refToInt++; }
};

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    MyClass mc(x);
    mc.changeValue();
    cout << mc.refToInt;
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles, but when it executes `mc.changeValue();` an exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00AB1884 in tests.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.
```

Why my code causes that exception?

Comment: The argument to the `MyClass` constructor is just like a local variable, and as such goes out of scope when the constructor body returns. Now guess what `refToInt` will reference... Try passing the argument by reference instead.

Comment: Undefined behavior due to the use of a dangling reference.

Comment: References as members is typically not a good idea.  This has nothing particularly to do with const-ness.

Comment: [Your compiler should have told you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74940b8d886977d7). With the right flags it should even refuse to compile.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, the constructor takes a `int` argument by value (which creates a temporary copy). You then store a reference to that temporary (which goes out of scope once the constructor finishes, so you have a dangling reference). 
Your `changeValue` function then attempts to update the value of the, long dead, temporary via that dangling reference, leading to undefined behaviour and (in your case (although the compiler could have validly done *anything*)) a crash.